# Trigger next level in our javascript game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

We are making a game for our school, it is fairly simple, however, we cannot figure out how to  make it trigger the next level. Currently, we have a button set to load a new page when they finish the level, but it is, obviously, very easy to cheat with this method. We were wondering how we could make it so when the red dot (character) reaches the top box, the next level will load. I will post level one for reference.

```
   <html>
<head>
<style>
            canvas, img {
            display:block; margin:1em auto; border:1px solid black;
            }
            canvas { 
            background:url(Clouds.png);
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #000"></canvas>
<script>
    (function () {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 500,
    height = 200,
    player = {
        x: width / 2,
        y: height - 15,
        width: 5,
        height: 5,
        speed: 3,
        velX: 0,
        velY: 0,
        jumping: false,
        grounded: false
    },
    keys = [],
    friction = 0.8,
    gravity = 0.3;

var boxes = [];

// dimensions
boxes.push({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 10,
    height: height
});
boxes.push({
    x: 0,
    y: height - 2,
    width: width,
    height: 50
});
boxes.push({
    x: width - 10,
    y: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: height
});

boxes.push({
    x: 120,
    y: 10,
    width: 80,
    height: 80
});
boxes.push({
    x: 170,
    y: 50,
    width: 80,
    height: 80
});
boxes.push({
    x: 220,
    y: 100,
    width: 80,
    height: 80
});
boxes.push({
    x: 270,
    y: 150,
    width: 40,
    height: 40
});

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function update() {
    // check keys
    if (keys[38] || keys[32] || keys[87]) {
        // up arrow or space
        if (!player.jumping && player.grounded) {
            player.jumping = true;
            player.grounded = false;
            player.velY = -player.speed * 2;
        }
    }
    if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {
        // right arrow
        if (player.velX < player.speed) {
            player.velX++;
        }
    }
    if (keys[37] || keys[65]) {
        // left arrow
        if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
            player.velX--;
        }
    }

    player.velX *= friction;
    player.velY += gravity;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();

    player.grounded = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        ctx.rect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);

        var dir = colCheck(player, boxes[i]);

        if (dir === "l" || dir === "r") {
            player.velX = 0;
            player.jumping = false;
        } else if (dir === "b") {
            player.grounded = true;
            player.jumping = false;
        } else if (dir === "t") {
            player.velY *= -1;
        }

    }

    if(player.grounded){
         player.velY = 0;
    }

    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;

    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function colCheck(shapeA, shapeB) {
    // get the vectors to check against
    var vX = (shapeA.x + (shapeA.width / 2)) - (shapeB.x + (shapeB.width / 2)),
        vY = (shapeA.y + (shapeA.height / 2)) - (shapeB.y + (shapeB.height / 2)),
        // add the half widths and half heights of the objects
        hWidths = (shapeA.width / 2) + (shapeB.width / 2),
        hHeights = (shapeA.height / 2) + (shapeB.height / 2),
        colDir = null;

    // if the x and y vector are less than the half width or half height, they we must be inside the object, causing a collision
    if (Math.abs(vX) < hWidths && Math.abs(vY) < hHeights) {
        // figures out on which side we are colliding (top, bottom, left, or right)
        var oX = hWidths - Math.abs(vX),
            oY = hHeights - Math.abs(vY);
        if (oX >= oY) {
            if (vY > 0) {
                colDir = "t";
                shapeA.y += oY;
            } else {
                colDir = "b";
                shapeA.y -= oY;
            }
        } else {
            if (vX > 0) {
                colDir = "l";
                shapeA.x += oX;
            } else {
                colDir = "r";
                shapeA.x -= oX;
            }
        }
    }
    return colDir;
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});


window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    update();
});
</script>
<br>
<center>
<input type="button" name="next" value="Click me when finished! No cheating! ;)" onclick="location.href='level2.html';">
</center>
<center>
<input type="button" name="restart" value="Restart" onclick="location.href='javagame.html';">
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course, once the user sees that the next level is called `level2.html`, there won't be anything to stop them from entering `level3.html`, `level4.html`, etc directly into the browser. I don't think there's any 100% reliable way to prevent people from cheating at a javascript game, but having a single page that loads data for each level as the user progresses might be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

In your update function you can add logic that checks if the player is in the position matching your finish condition. Then in the conditional set location.href='level2.html';

I'm assuming that condition would be using the colCheck function with the player and the top box as arguments and looking for a specific return value, that can be an exercise for you to complete. The general code to move to the next level would look like:

```
if(playerReachedFinish()) {
  location.href = 'level2.html';
}
```